# Android browser Javascript onclick event not receiving callbacks

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events

I have a web application that has to be run on Android.

There are images on the web page that have `onClick` event listener (Javascript).
For some reason, the `onClick` event works only after **A LOT** of touches on the image.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using `onTouchStart` event instead of `onClick` event.